# How can I bring my div to the foreground with its background color?

Tags: html, css

#Preface I am relatively new to HTML and CSS if this has been answered elsewhere I would appreciate direction to something that gives me a solution.

Below is the code I have, I want the .Divclass to appear infront of my backround element with it's red background.

```
* {
  background-image: url(https://www.pixelstalk.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Treugolnik-triangle-illuminati-Wallpapers-High-Resolution.jpg);
        
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 1960px 1080px;
}

.divclass {
  height: 230px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  color: red;
  border: solid 1px rgb(253, 253, 253);
  text-align: center;   
  font-size: x-large;
}
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details.

Comment: with your very vague description I would assume that you look for `z-index`. As a site note:  `* { background-image: ... }` is a terrible CSS declaration as the background image will be added to every single element you have.

Comment: Don't use the star selector; it selects EVERYTHING IN THE VIEW and applies whatever attributes you specify.

Comment: I will review the tour and how to ask questions, I probably should have mentioned I tried the z-index. I believe because I applied the star selector it overwrites what ever element I'm trying to bring to the front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below snippet. The div is in front of the background image with a red background.

Let me know if this is what your desired output is

```css
section {
  background-image: url(https://www.pixelstalk.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Treugolnik-triangle-illuminati-Wallpapers-High-Resolution.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 1960px 1080px;
  padding: 10px;
}


.divclass {
  height: 230px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: red;
  border: solid 1px rgb(253, 253, 253);
  text-align: center;   
  font-size: x-large;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="divclass">Hi</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the most concise answer and to the point, I appreciate the help. I see you got rid of the star selector, looks like that was my main issue.

Answer (score -1):

```css
*{
    background-image: url('https://www.pixelstalk.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Treugolnik-triangle-illuminati-Wallpapers-High-Resolution.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 1960px 1080px;
}

.divclass {
    height: 230px;
    width: 300px;
    /*color: red;  This only makes the text color red */
    background: #f00;
    border: solid 1px rgb(253, 253, 253);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: x-large;
}
```

```html
<div class=divclass> Hi </div>
```

Note the display: flex that was added to center the text, rather than using text: center which won't center it vertically.

Comment: No need to add flex which does nothing to the code that was asked for. Also you should first address the fundemental issue of the `*`-selector that applies the background-image to every element. If you fix that, then the issue will also fix itself.

Comment: Yes, that's true. 
I used the flex because it seemed like they wanted the text centred.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.